# Excel COUNTIFS with OR condition

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to count cells based on several conditions. Two of these conditions refer to the same column and should be OR-ed. I know I can add two COUNTIFS, but I figured there must be a better way, which I have not yet found.

Example:
These are my source cells (columns A to D)

```
    A String    B String    C String    YearMonth
    12345A      XYZ         UVW1        201301
    ABCDE       XYZ         UVW1        201302
    BCDEF       XYZ         UVW1        201301
    12345A      XYZ         UVW1        201303
    T2345       XYZ         UVW1        201304
    T2345       XYZ         UVW1        201301
    ABCDE       XYZ         UVW1        201301
```

...and this is how I want my results (columns H to M)

```
    Title  XYZ  201301  201302  201303  201304
    UVW1             1       0       1       1
    UVW2             0       0       0       0
    UVW3             0       0       0       0
    UVW4             0       0       0       0
    UVW5             0       0       0       0
    UVW6             0       0       0       0
    UVW7             0       0       0       0
```

The bold number 1 should be 2 using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B:$B=$I$1)*($C:$C=$H2)*($D:$D=J$1)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID($A:$A;1;2);{"1?";"T2"};0)))
```

Unfortunately wildcards does not seem to work.
Since the results really is in a different sheet the following formula, that will work, will be uncomfortably long and time consuming. It also repeats conditions which I don't like.

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B;$I$1;$C:$C;$H2;$D:$D;J$1;$A:$A;"1*")+COUNTIFS($B:$B;$I$1;$C:$C;$H2;$D:$D;J$1;$A:$A;"T2*")
```

Any ideas on a working formula that does not repeat conditions?

EDIT: Also, as agtoever pointed out I could add a new column to sort by, but unfortunately, adding a column would mean going through some almost unmaintainable macros, something I hope to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to realize that matching 1? or T2 can be considered two separate criteria, but they should be combined with + instead of *. Since they are mutually exclusive, their sum will always be 0 or 1.

```
=SUM(($B$2:$B$8=$I$1)*($C$2:$C$8=$H3)*($D$2:$D$8=K$1)*
     ((LEFT($A$2:$A$8,1)="1")+(LEFT($A$2:$A$8,2)="T2")))
```

[image: sum of conditions using + for or]

Starting from your SUMPRODUCT option, I first noticed that it had only one argument, so I switched to just using SUM. I also changed from handling the whole column to just the range I needed, because recalculations were taking so long on my underpowered system. If you care about speed, it might be important to avoid processing the whole column, but you probably have more experience with that than I do.

Comment: Using SUMPRODUCT instead of SUM in your formula worked for me. When using SUM it returned 1 instead of 2 in the cell mentioned in my question (J2). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create the results, use the [Pivot table function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx) that Excel provides. These are the steps:

- Select your source data (columns A:D)
- Insert a pivot table (often found in the "Insert" and/or "Data" tab of your ribbon)
- Set C string to be your row headers
- Set YearMonth to be your column headers
- Set B string in your report filter
- Set A string (or any other field) in the values area and make sure the items are *counted* (not summed)
- Adjust further to your liking.

To filter the results on A string, you have two options:

1. Add a column to your original table that checks your conditions (in your case something like this in row 2: `=OR(LEFT(A2;2)="T2";LEFT(A2;1)="1")` and add this field to your Pivot table report filter and filter on `TRUE`.
2. Add String A to your report filter, and manually select each value that you want to show. Note that this assumes that the number of values is relatively limited, because otherwise, this would be quite some work to maintain the right filtering.

Personally, I like the first one better, because of better transparency and maintainability.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, but I do not seem to be able to count only those "A strings" starting with 1 or T2.

Comment: Edited the answer. Sorry that I did not include that aspect of your question the first time.

Comment: Option 2 is not an option for me as the amount of data is rather large. The first one might work (even in my solution without the pivot table) though adding a column in my case is not as easy as it may seem, since my source data is used by macros that I hope to keep my hands off for as long as possible. Thanks again though - useful answer (can't upvote due to lack of rep).